# Is it okay to ask about video game console hacks/exploit?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Some [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/616249/2284570) ask things which involve circumventing encryption in the answer.

There are also questions which ask how to write programs for getting homebrew software running, while certain company fills lawsuits against homebrews applications enablers.

Is it acceptable to ask or answer such questions?

Comment: In the case of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/616249/2284570 "Wii Fit data format?"), there's the fact that the abusive flag is too general, so they have been dismissed. I recognize creating a flagging category for illegal contents would be part of another question.

Comment: Given that [virus writing questions are ok](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187593/should-virus-or-illegal-activity-related-questions-code-be-allowed) I'm guessing this is fine (assuming all the usual on topicness rules are followed)

Comment: There are no "abusive" flags on the post you linked.  There are two offensive flags (one on the question, one on the accepted answer), both of which were declined.

Comment: @RichardTingle : "not those openly illicit" which seems to be the case of some answers [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/616249/2284570 "Wii Fit data format?")

Comment: By "illicit", do you mean illegal? I don't see any violations of the law (though I only know US law) there.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: I was quoting an answer from the link [Ricard Tingle](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/220332/richard-tingle) posted.

Comment: My own stance is that I won't touch them. The more clearly abusive ones may get downvoted/flagged. But in the end, it's the admins who are responsible for defining the community standard -- it's their server, it's their responsibility.

Comment: @RobertHarvey : Ok, I was applying those [rules](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#idp54168080) to stackoverflow which is a mistake.

Comment: Yeah, hard to see the equivalence between reverse-engineering a savegame and hacking into someone's email.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta : I didn't said where the mistake was :) .